# Create organization nuget feed in azure pipelines missing

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create an organization (not project) private nuget feed in azure pipelines but there is no such option. I can create nuget feed on a project but not on organization level.
How do I enable this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the feed on a project, you can define who can access this feed. For your case you should select organization. Then you can use this feed from other projects inside the same organization.

[image]

From another project you will be able to access this feed.

[image]